# Notions of positivity for q-polynomials

Tags: polynomials, positivity

What are some existing notions of positivity (or nonnegativity) for $\mathbf{R}[q]$ such that all $q$-integers $[n]_q = 1+q+...+q^{n-1}$ are positive, as well as all polynomials that can be expressed in the form $[m_1]_q [m_2]_q \dots / [n_1]_q [n_2]_q \dots$, such as the algebraically natural $q$-Catalan numbers $[2n]_q / [n]_q [n+1]_q$?

Of course, one such property is that the polynomial takes on only nonnegative values when $q \geq 0$, but I suspect that there are others.

Note however that the coefficients need not be nonnegative; e.g., the cyclotomic polynomial $1-q+q^2$ can be written as $[6]_q / [2]_q [3]_q$.

Comment: Another natural notion of positivity would be a positivity of the classical limit at $q\to 1$.

Comment: There is also the concept of being the result of a subtraction-free rational expression (e.g., arXiv:1307.8425v4).

Comment: Can one give an intrinsic characterization of such polynomials?

Comment: If you want the set of all "positive" polynomials to form a cone, then the smallest such cone is genererated by products of cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n(q)$ excluding $\Phi_1(q)=q-1$.

Comment: Apropos of Darij Grinberg's comment and my query pertaining to that comment, Sergey Fomin has explained to me that a polynomial in $q$ can be written as a ratio of polynomials with non-negative coefficients if and only if the polynomial is positive on the positive ray.

Comment: A stronger notion of positivity for a polynomial $p(x)$ is that $|p(z)|\leq p(|z|)$ for all complex $z$. Assuming $p(0)\neq 0$ and the $\gcd$ of the exponents appearing in $p(x)$ to be $1$, an even stronger version is that $|p(z)|< p(|z|)$ for all complex $z$ not on the positive real axis. An example of such a polynomial with a negative coefficients is $p(x) = 2+2x-x^2+2x^3+2x^4$, while the polynomial $1-x+x^2$ does not satisfy the weaker version.